# SVG in the Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, svg

I know it's not supported natively, but are there any JS Shims that render into a canvas object or something that would allow me to render SVG on the native android browser? (Not Opera, etc since I'd like to avoid having the user need to install another browser)

Comment: [Fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/) supports rendering SVG on canvas. Take a look at a [demo that does exactly that](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/svg_rendering/) (careful, loads slowly due to large number of SVG shapes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is this library:

http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

Basically, you would detect if the browser is capable of rendering svgs, and if it can't, you would render the SVG to canvas.

Comment: Please don't do browser/platform sniffing. Detect if the browser is capable of rendering SVG instead, see e.g http://modernizr.com.