# How to inject inline SVG with javascript on Android 4.2

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, svg, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a PHP web app with AngularJS front end. Some of our assets are SVG format which we insert dynamically using directives.

```
<div ng-bind-html="block.arrow_svg | unsafe"></div>
```

In the code above, `block.arrow_svg` is a string containing SVG code: `'<svg>...</svg>' and the`unsafe` Angular filter is just a shortcut for preventing escaping of markup.

This works fine normally, but apparently Android 4.2 doesn't play nicely with inline SVG via javascript. I don't fully understand that limitation, but I'm fairly confident it is the explanation for why the assets aren't appearing on Android 4.2 devices. If I hardcode the same inline SVG code into the static page (outside the Angular template) it appears normally on Android 4.2.

Does anyone know of a workaround to allow my inline SVG to work dynamically via javascript/angular?

Comment: @Julien for some reason it's not appearing. Not sure why...

Comment: These questions might help you: [SVG in the Android Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125829/svg-in-the-android-browser) and [Using javascript to render svg in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229091/using-javascript-to-render-svg-in-android)

Comment: @Julien that answer is about JavaScript in the img tag... But I'm not doing that.